# Zero set of prime ideal

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0,$ but not necessarily algebraically closed.
Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $k[X]$ (where $X$ is an $n$-tuple of variables), and $V := \{x \in K^n: \forall p \in P\ p(x) = 0\}$ be its zero set.
Is $V$ irreducible over $k$?

Equivalently: let $I(V) := \{q \in k[X]:\ \forall x \in V\ q(x) = 0\}$.
Is $I(V)$ prime (or everything)?

**Edit**: the original question has negative answer. What happens if moreover $V(P)$ has the same dimension as the zero set of $P$ inside the algebraic closure of $k$?

I would like a reference with either a proof or a counterexample.

What happens when $k$ is the reals?

Answer (score 6):

Let $k = \mathbb{R}$ and let $P$ be the prime ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ generated by $h := y^4 + y^2 + (x^2-1)^2$.  According to Sage¹ (though I'm sure this is easy to check by other means), $h$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, so certainly in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$, so $P$ is prime.  But $h(x,y)=0$ over $\mathbb{R}$ can only occur for $(x,y) = (\pm 1,0)$ for obvious reasons of positivity, and indeed does happen for those two points.  And $V = \{(1,0),(-1,0)\}$ certainly isn't irreducible, nor is the ideal $I(V)$ prime.

Geometrically, $\{h=0\}$ is an irreducible curve with exactly two singular points (ordinary double points), which are its only two real points.

1. Actually checking over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$:

```
sage: R.<x,y> = PolynomialRing(QQbar,2)
sage: factor(y^4 + y^2 + (x^2-1)^2)
x^4 + y^4 + (-2)*x^2 + y^2 + 1
```